# Which has better performance, Java or DB functions?

Tags: java, mysql, database, performance, function

I'm writing a Web App and I don't know which technique is faster: to implement some code using Java native or database functions (mysql or maridb in my case).

i.e:
Using Java:

```
String new_string = my_string.replace('-','');
Query query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id=" + new_string;
```

i.e:
Using Database functions:

```
Query query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id=REPLACE(" + new_string + ",'-','');
```

Thanks!

PS: Please, forget the bad code, I know it. It's just to explain you the idea :-)

Comment: If the question is only about an individual string replace in your codebase, the difference is likely not noticeable, and this is hardly the bottleneck in your application. The first version is simpler (and doesn't include RDBMS-specific syntax in the query), making it preferable.

Comment: Thanks you all. @yshavit, I knew it, that's the reason of my PS. Thanks! :)

Comment: Flip a coin; it will give you the right answer.  Sometimes.

Comment: Do _not_ hide an indexed column in a SQL function -- That _will_ lose the race.  (No, your example does not do such.)

Comment: Do neither, learn some library like jOOQ, iBatis, Hibernate, ..... You'll get bad performance from both (I'd bet: autocommit, no prepared statements, etc.) and SQL injection as a bonus. Things you're trying to optimize are basically irrelevant for speed when accessing a DB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The performance difference is going to be negligible or there would more likely be no difference at all. I would say do the replacement in Java so that your SQL logs are cleaner if you ever want to look at them to debug / see what's been happening. It's much easier to search/read through the replaced strings I would think.